# jQuery Append isn't affecting page content

Tags: jquery, api, twitter, append, tumblr

Here is a JSFiddle for ease: http://jsfiddle.net/u5XmR/

I have a lot going on, but my main concern is why the $("#content").append(); is not changing anything on my page.

Specifically this function should adjust and change the content dynamically:

```
function findpost(timestamp, blog){
    //console.log(blog);
    var length = blog.length;
    for(var e=0; e<length; e++){
        var type = blog[e+1];
        if(timestamp === blog[e]){
            if(type === 0){
                $("#content").append("\
                    <div id='post' class='photo'>\
                    <img src='"+blog[e+2]+"' width='400px'/>\
                    </div>\
                ");
                console.log("Photo");
            } else if(type === 1){
                console.log("Video");
            } else if(type === 2){
                $("#content").append("\
                    <div id='post' class='link' />\
                    "+blog[e+2]+" "+blog[e+3]+"\
                    </div>\
                ");
                console.log("Link!");
            } else if(type === 3){
                console.log("Text!");
            } else if(type === 4){
                console.log("Tweet!");
            } else {
                console.warn("ERROR!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the loop you're calling `findpost` in you're first `.empty()`ing the `#content` div. This is pretty wasteful, and after some iterations the `blog` variable is empty, so `findpost` doesn't do anything. As a result you only see the last number and not any `<div id='post'>` elements. Why are you emptying the div each iteration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are clearing the `$('#content')` everytime in the for loop

Check out this updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/u5XmR/6/

In the `.done()`

This is what you need to change:

```
$("#content").empty();

for(var e=0;e<length;e++){
    $("#content").append( e +"<br>");

    ...
```

Comment: Bahah! You're so right. Thanks so much! I guess it takes a second eye sometime to see something so plain!